# Select a range of number

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
SELECT nummer
   FROM tabell_med_nummer
  WHERE SUBSTR(nummer, -1) = 0
```

This query selects a number in the table tabell_med_nummer, that ends with "0". For example it will select 1000, 1010, 1020, but not 1001, 1002 and so on.

I need to get a range based on this. For example 1000-1100, or 1010-1023. The size of the range is variable. What it ends with is not important, but it have to select a number that ends with "0" like 1010.

The tricky part is that not every number exists in the table. So if 1004 doesn't exists in the table, end I need a range on 100, it can't start at 1000.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

As requested:

```
    +----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                 | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ALL   | NULL                          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL |   19 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | index | telefonnummer,telefonnummer_2 | telefonnummer | 5       | NULL | 1001 | Using index; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL   | NULL                          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL | 4568 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | index | telefonnummer,telefonnummer_2 | telefonnummer | 5       | NULL | 1001 | Using index; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL   | telefonnummer,telefonnummer_2 | NULL          | NULL    | NULL | 1001 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I changed some table and field names and added a few joins and where statments:

```
SELECT t1.telefonnummer start, t2.telefonnummer end, t1.kundenummer kundenummer, t1.fornavn fornavn, t1.etternavn etternavn, t1.bedriftsnavn bedriftsnavn, t1.organisasjonsnummer organisasjonsnummer, t1.partnerID partnerID

FROM TELEFONNUMMERTILDELING t1

JOIN TELEFONNUMMERTILDELING t2
ON t1.telefonnummer % 10 = 0
AND t1.telefonnummer <= t2.telefonnummer

JOIN TELEFONNUMMERTILDELING t3
ON t3.telefonnummer BETWEEN t1.telefonnummer AND t2.telefonnummer

JOIN TELEFONNUMMERTILDELING_POSTNUMMER p
ON p.postnummer = 4085

JOIN TELEFONNUMMERTILDELING_FYLKE f
ON f.ID = p.fylkeID GROUP BY start, end

HAVING end - start + 1 = COUNT(*)
AND end - start + 1 = 50
AND (kundenummer IS NULL OR kundenummer = '')
AND (fornavn IS NULL OR fornavn = '')
AND (etternavn IS NULL OR etternavn = '')
AND (bedriftsnavn IS NULL OR bedriftsnavn = '')
AND (organisasjonsnummer IS NULL OR organisasjonsnummer = '')
AND partnerID = 1001
```

Comment: Could you show some sample data and your expected result?  I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to achieve (it sounds like you will provide the *range* e.g. `100` as an input, from which you want to obtain start and end points as an output?  but it isn't clear exactly what your restrictions are: especially with respect to your final sentence "*So if 1004 doesn't exists in the table, end I need a range on 100, it can't start at 1000.*").

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can try to explain it in another way: I have a table with a lot of numbers. I need to select a variable sized range. But the range that are selected have to have every numbers in between. 100-200 can't be selected if theres a missing number between 100 and 200 in the table. But if every number between 100 and 200 exists in the table, this range is OK and can be selected.

If the table contains 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 - the range 1-3, 5-7, 9-10 is OK, but not any other range. If I need to select a range of for example 5 numbers, this will not be possible in this example,

Comment: and will therefor result empty.

Comment: But then, since you are forcibly excluding all numbers except those ending in `0`, won't it necessarily be that one cannot form any range that does not skip any numbers?  For example, even if your table contains all of `10` through `30`, you cannot return the range `10-30` because `11`, `12`, etc. are all being excluded by the filter criterion.

Comment: Not all numbers have to end with 0, just the first number in the range. So it have to start with 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- get the start and end points
SELECT   t1.nummer AS start, t2.nummer AS end

-- pair every possible start number with every potential end number
FROM     tabell_med_nummer t1
    JOIN tabell_med_nummer t2
      ON t1.nummer % 10 = 0 AND t1.nummer <= t2.nummer

-- obtain every number in between
    JOIN tabell_med_nummer t3
      ON t3.nummer BETWEEN t1.nummer AND t2.nummer

-- group into potential ranges
GROUP BY start, end

-- now limit only to contiguous ranges
  HAVING end - start + 1 = COUNT(*)

-- and those that contain the desired number of records
     AND end - start + 1 = ?
```

If `nummer` is not guaranteed to be unique, e.g. with a `UNIQUE` constraint, then you will need to replace `COUNT(*)` with the less performant `COUNT(DISTINCT t3.nummer)` or else replace `t3` with `(SELECT DISTINCT nummer FROM tabell_med_nummer)`.

Comment: I got an error message: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 13

Comment: You have to replace the `?` with the size of your desired range.

Comment: Oh, sorry, monday morning... ;) I set the range size to 10. The site where the query is places never seem to end, and I had to restart apache. The same thing happend when I runned the query directly in MySQL Client. Any suggestion what I might doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an index on `tabell_med_nummer.nummer`?

Comment: I have an indexed ID in this table.

Comment: Perhaps my last comment should have read "*create an index on...*".

Comment: 100 rows in set (18 min 32.71 sec)
The result seems OK :)

Gonna index it :)

Comment: alter table tabell_med_nummer nummer(nummer) doesn't seem to reduce the query time.

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE tabell_med_nummer ADD INDEX (nummer);`.

Comment: Sorry, that was what i ment

Comment: Please edit your question to include output of [`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html).

Comment: Did you find my EXPLAIN SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

add another condition in your `WHERE` clause.

```
 SELECT nummer
   FROM tabell_med_nummer
  WHERE SUBSTR(nummer, -1) = 0 AND
        nummer BETWEEN 1000 AND 1100
```

Comment: "BETWEEN 1000 AND 1100" will select between 1000 and 1100 even if for example 1054 doesn't exists. So I can't do it this way :/